# URL redirection to a non-http url, in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect

I'm using nginx as reverse proxy. How can a URL redirection be set up in nginx's server block, such that the URL to redirect to is a **non-http url**?

For instance, I have a url of the type:

`http://example.com/user_uuid/a0d525aa-d755-11e5-b5d2-0a1d41d68578/14084561234/`

I want to redirect from the above to the non-http url:

`sms:14084561234?body:my photo is located at http://example.com/photos/a0d525aa-d755-11e5-b5d2-0a1d41d68578/`

When this non-http url hits the browser, the device's native SMS app opens up, pre-filling the SMS with the phone number 1-408-456-1234 and the body with the text appearing after `?body` in the non-http url. Naturally, this is applicable to mobile devices only.

Is this sort of a thing possible? If so, can you give me an example? Note that in the first URL, the `uuid` and the number are generated *dynamically*, based on some prior inputs.

---

I already know how to implement redirection *within* my web application's code, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration works:

```
server {
    listen 99;
    server_name test.so;

    location /user_uuid {
        rewrite /user_uuid/(.+)/([^/]+) "sms:$2?body:my photo is located at http://example.com/$1/" redirect;
    }

}
```

**Sample output**:

```
curl -I -H "Host: test.so" http://localhost:99/user_uuid/uuid/phone/

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.7.11
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 00:45:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: sms:phone?body:my photo is located at http://example.com/uuid/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll test it and get back to you.